# Undefined is not a function (evaluating 'ReactComponentTreeHook.purgeUnmountedComponents()'

Tags: react-native

I'm facing this error and tried to research from the internet but no luck. 
It just suddenly happened without reason so I don't know how to reproduce the error.
I followed this solution (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8454). Tried to uninstall, install react js again but still the same.
Can someone help to take a look at this ?
Many thanks.
This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeLeadership",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@monterosa/react-native-parallax-scroll": "^1.0.4",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "dateformat": "^2.0.0",
    "k-core": "0.0.1-alpha.2",
    "lodash-node": "^3.10.2",
    "native-base": "^2.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-debbuger": "0.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.47.1",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-autolink": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-confetti": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-console-panel": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-drop-refresh": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-menu": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.15",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.25.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-keyboard-manager": "^4.0.10-3",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-media-kit": "git+https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-media-kit.git#pull/30/head",
    "react-native-modal": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-modal-wrapper": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-mov-to-mp4": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-native-video-player": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-orientation": "git+https://git@github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation.git",
    "react-native-photo-view": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-progress-bar-classic": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-simple-modal": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-thumbnail": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-triangle": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-persist": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "17.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "eslint": "^3.11.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.7.1",
    "jest": "^17.0.0",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.android.js

```
import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import AppProvider from './src/index';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeLeadership', () => AppProvider);
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import store from './app/appStore';
import AppContainer from './app/appContainer';
import Splashscreen from './app/splashScreen';
import I18n from './app/i18n';
import SwipUnlocker from './app/SwipeUnlocker';

const Orientation = require('react-native-orientation');

class AwesomeLeadership extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer /> ;
  }
}

class AppProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isInitializing: true,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      if (store.getState().isHydrated) {
        unsubscribe();
        I18n.locale = 'sv-SE';
        this.setState({
          isInitializing: false,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isInitializing) {
      return <Splashscreen/>;
    } else {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <AwesomeLeadership/>
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default AppProvider;
```

[image]

Comment: To get the best advice here, try to add as much detail as possible, and refrain from adding chatty material. All of the body text in this question was not relevant: how long you have been stuck, that you have "googled", that you still cannot fix it, and that you would like people to look at it are all obvious or irrelevant. But we don't know what code produced this error, which is perhaps the most critical detail of all. What did you do to produce the error? How can readers reproduce it? Would you update the post?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I beleive it was connected with different versions of React and React Native.

For example, RN 0.51 requires a peer dependency of React 16.0. In my case I had 16 alpha and that caused the error. I suggest you try to install the corresponding version of React.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error...
I just change react-native version to 0.49.0. work fine.